# Silverlight Navigation(PRISM) to show in Browser?

Tags: silverlight, navigation, prism

I'm not even sure how to properly ask this question. I'm new to Silverlight and what I'm trying to accomplish is web application that can be referenced using hyperlinks in browser like so:

```
myapp.com/MaintainUser?UserKey=1
```

So, I already created modular app with PRISM and using their **RegionManager.RequestNavigate** and passing URL's here and there. Seems to be working. But browser does not reflect what I'm doing. URL always stays at

```
myapp.com
```

I'm not even sure if what I'm doing possible. And if it is, can you point me in correct direction? Or at least terminology.. I thought Navigation will take care of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called *deep linking* and it's supported by the Silverlight runtime since version 3. However, you should not confuse this with Prism navigation, which is not integrated with the browser.

[Here's an quick intro to the standard Silverlight navigation framework.](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/The-Silverlight-3-Navigation-Framework.aspx)